# Trying to Highlight the Value From Conditional Formatting

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight the Column J using Conditional Formatting in case of first value before / >139 OR Last value after / >89 then highlight. I have tried but its not working. your help will be appreciated.

```
=OR(IF(TRIM(LEFT(J3,FIND("/",J3)-1))>139),IF(RIGHT(J3,FIND("/",J3)-2)>89))
```

[Sheetlink](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZIdYKMvHuEhFtsbffbI24L1xqJl33RPLn-Mem5UjZoE/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=(REGEXEXTRACT(J1, "^\d+")*1>139)+(REGEXEXTRACT(J1, "\d+$")*1>89)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for interest, you can get your find/right/left formula to work as well but you have to use -- (or value or *1 like @player0) to convert the substring into a number:

```
=OR(--LEFT(J3,FIND("/",J3)-1)>139,--RIGHT(J3,len(J3)-FIND("/",J3))>89)
```

[image]